# Chatbot Using Javanese language

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, chatbot

i want to make a *chatbot* using *javanese language*. is it possible if i use *dialogflow* and utilize speech regognition and text to speech?. Please, give me suggestion. i really appreciate about some advice

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help), paying special attention to the sections on how to ask good questions and what is considered on topic for this site. Stack Overflow is here primarily to address specific programming issues, rather than helping you design your project or recommend tools.

Comment: You might want to do some research on some options or tutorials out there. You really shouldn't be asking how to create something but how could to fix something.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned in the comments, you better do your research for this kind of question. The answer to your question is YES. Dialogflow supports the Japanese language for most of its features including text, STT, TTS, and Sentiment analysis. Here is the link to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/language).